# httpd: how to save 127.0.0.1:81 as a hostname in /etc/hosts

Tags: apache

I am using archlinux and installed systemd-nspawn container:

The host and the containers both have httpd installed.

In the host server the port is 80

In the container server the port is 81

What i observered is 127.0.0.1:80 refers to host and 127.0.0.1:81 refers to container.

I think by default linux considers 127.0.0.1 as 127.0.0.1:80

I thought of saving 127.0.0.1:81 as localhost in the /etc/hosts

My file /etc/hosts in the container is as follows:
127.0.0.1:81 gauranga
127.0.0.1 nityananda

When i try in the containers chroium http://gauranga it ways `This webpage is not available`

when i try in the containers chromium http://nityananda it works and shows the hosts /srv/http root directory contents

how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **/etc/hosts** file is to override or define local do DNS resolution on your machine.

DNS is the service that translates domain names to ip addresses so that computers can communicate with each other.

Ports are another concept. Ports are more like mailboxes, a computer can have more than one service ( smtp , http , https etc.. ) and each of them listens on their own special mailbox. That way different services don't have access to each others data.

In other words when you connect to google.com:80 you are
1. First resolving google.com to its ip address
2. Use the ip to connect to the 80 port or mailbox, the one used for the web/http

So in short you don't need ( and can't) specify a port on **/etc/hosts** your host entry will have the effect on all ports since this is done in a previous step.